# Why is my javascript not running in order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, console

In code1, it outputs undefined as expected. However code2 outputs the array already with the "hello" pushed inside. I don't understand why it didn't run the code in order.

```
function drawChart(chart) {
        console.log(chartData) //code1
        var chartData = [];
        console.log(chartData) //code2

       chartData.push("hello")
}
```

Comment: The console API (especially in Chrome) behaves kind-of asynchronously, and it really confuses people.

Comment: Alternate duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync